# Can Branch.io deep link URL's be customized

Tags: branch.io

A regular deep link dynamically generated using the iOS/Android SDK's might look like this: https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD

Would I be able to dynamically generate a deep link that would look something like: https://example.app.link/jsmith49
this would greatly help for marketing purposes

If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackie from Branch here.

You can definitely use a link alias to replace the standard encoded short URL (e.g. https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD -> https://example.app.link/jsmith49). Note that link aliases must be unique, otherwise a 409 error will occur.

If you are creating Branch links via the SDK and/or HTTP API, you'd need to set the value of 'alias' key. Please refer to our documentation on configuring links [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#configure-deep-links). 
Alternatively, you can use the Branch dashboard to create links by entering the link alias on the 'Configure Options' step [here](https://dashboard.branch.io/quick-links/qlc/config/).

Let us know if you have more questions. Hope this helps!

Comment: do I pass the alias field, just the trailing part of the url or must I pass thie full url? also what about when using a custom domain?

Comment: Hey there! You'd add the trailing part of the url with the alias key. The value will be appended to the app.link or custom domain which will look something like example.app.link/test_link or custom.domain/test_link.